# Unable to identify an object using QTP which is removed from UI once action is done on it

Tags: qtp

I have a situation here. The application that I am automating is a JavaScript app with a .NET wrapper. One of the web tables has the functionality where in after selecting and doing an action on a row, this row is removed from the table and no longer in the UI. The script fails upon rerun since it is looking for that object.

Can someone please help me with this?

QTP version 11.0

I am using two properties that does not change in the objects but still failing:

```
Browser("Browser").Page("page").Frame("frame").WebElement("htmltag:=DIV","class:=ntb-cell").Drag
Browser("Browser").Page("page").Frame("frame").WebElement("html tag:=DIV","class:=ntb-cell").Drop
```

This object is removed from the screen once the drag-drop action and a click action is completed. This object also has a dynamically changing text field which I have used reg exp to capture.

Comment: What fails, exactly, and when?

Comment: I think, I am understanding the problem myself only now. let me see I can explain it.

Comment: I have a webtable which has data populated through a filter ie. the webtable has data blocks from various filters. The problem is I am not able to uniquely identify a row and do action on it. The first run works but subsequent runs fail because the row has been removed from the webtable. The error I get object is not uniquely identified when I use the code I posted in my question.

Comment: So if the object is gone, what do you expect to happen upon second run?

Comment: Take the next item in the table and do the action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you said so far, the item addressed is present in the first pass and cannot be uniquely identified in the second pass. This would mean that after the first pass, there is more than one item matching your description.

To diagnose further, please switch of smart identification globally. Next, re-run your script. Does it still fail like before? Good. Then you will get "Cannot uniquely identify object (there is more than one object matching your description) in the second pass.

Try highlighting the separate instances of the object in question:

```
Browser("Browser").Page("page").Frame("frame").WebElement("htmltag:=DIV","class:=ntb-cell").Highlight
```

will still fail, but

```
Browser("Browser").Page("page").Frame("frame").WebElement("htmltag:=DIV","class:=ntb-cell","index:=0").Highlight
```

should highlight the first instance, "`index:=1`" the second one, and so on. If so, go and look at the properties of those objects, and find which one you can take to differentiate between them. If you cannot find any, you must use the index property.

If in the context of the second run you find no matches at all, even using the index property, you might have "missed" a page refresh, and the object reference created internally by QTP is invalid (i.e. adresses a GUI object using a specific windows handle but the object has been replaced, or recreated, by a GUI object which now has a different windows handle). This should not happen with descriptive programming as you use it, but just to make sure, insert a

```
Browser("Browser").Page("page").RefreshObject
```

call before the drag and drop calls. Then re-try, and re-diagnose using the steps described above. This should shed enough light onto the topic so you might find a solution (then please post it!), or enables us to give better answers (or to refine this one).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am going to try this today and I will keep you posted on how this works out.

Comment: The RefreshObject worked superbly. I did not change anything else. I just added this line of code before my drag/drop statements.